# Selenium python returning the page Head but not the Body

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've been banging my head with this one for a few hours. I built a code a few weeks ago that uses python-selenium and runs on [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb) to scrape a [supermarket website](https://www.continente.pt/stores/continente/pt-pt/public/Pages/category.aspx?cat=Mercearia#/).

Everything was well and and good until today when the code stopped working. To understand why it was breaking I displayed the page source and to my surprise realized that I'm getting the page header with the javascript (which I don't understand) and not body at all, literally `<body></body>`. The code itself works fine, I have tested it on other URLs such as python.org/.

I am using selenium 3.141.0 with python 3.6.9, chromium-chromedriver 79.0.3945.79, on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. And this is the minimal code to reproduce my issue.

```py
# if running directly on google colab
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!pip install selenium
```

I tried various different user-agents to try fooling any anti-scrapers they might have. Checked for iFrames but there are none.

```py
import time 
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=" + user_agent)

wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
url = "https://www.continente.pt/stores/continente/pt-pt/public/Pages/category.aspx?cat=Mercearia#/"
wd.get(url)
time.sleep(30)
print(soup(wd.page_source))
```

Do I have to run some javascript to load the contents? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: If your run this script and remove the `--headless` option, does the page actually load? They might be trying to detect web scrapers.

Comment: I tried to load the url using Chromedriver but it doesn't work. The url can be loaded on IE webdriver, but the script gets stuck at `wd.get(url)`.

Comment: @GregBurghardt if I remove the `--headless` option I can't run the code from a server any more and the ultimate goal is to have it running automatically on AWS.

Comment: @JiWei could you get the Body of the page with the IE webdriver?

Comment: I was just trying to figure out if headless mode behaved differently than the non headless mode. Also, which version of Chrome is running on the server?

Comment: I would guess that soup's having trouble parsing this page.  It's bloated with javascript.  You'll see it even confuses Chrome when it tries to display the source because there is HTML inside of <script> tags.  (This may also affect your scripts and the webdriver's ability to parse the DOM... hard to say without seeing exceptions or code...)

Comment: @Diogo IE webdriver displays the Body but doesn't return the Body dom structure.

Comment: @GregBurghardt, JiWei and pcalkins very mysteriously the code started working again. I now get the HTML Body, having done absolutely no changes in the code. I find this very confusing and worrying (because the problem could come back any time)

Comment: were there changes made to the web site?

Comment: @pcalkins there are no changes that can be seen with the human eye, which doesn't mean that none were made. I did not think of saving the HTML before so I can't compare that unfortunately